# detect to rising, stable and falling point in non-smooth rectangular wave

Tags: matlab, filters, signal-analysis, edge-detection, smoothing

I am working on basic signal processing problems in MATLAB. I have found a signal from the internet (i don't remember the site exactly). The data is organized in column wise. 1st and 2nd column is data and 3rd column is a rectangular wave. The rectangular wave is not very smooth. So I decided to detect four points as shown in the figure. I spend 2 days to find the exact solution but i couldn't find any solution to the detect those four points.
I tried few things:
1) finding the difference between the points to get 1,2,3 and 4 points.
but it doesn't work.
2) Median Filter to smooth the wave.
[image]
Anyone, please give some suggestion to detect these points in MATLAB

Comment: @Peter i have deleted the comment which you though as off-topic

Answer (score 6):

The usual approach to change detection is [the CUSUM algorithm.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUSUM)

I've done an implementation that just addresses the level (mean) change issue. It's included (in R) below.

The black line is the noise-free data, the red line is the noisy data and the blue bars are the detected breaks (for this realization).

This just addresses the level change; to address the three zones: low level, changing level, and high level, you'll need to figure out the way to estimate the mean in the changing level (perhaps assume a rise time and fix the two levels?).

[The code below is based on this document.](http://chamilo2.grenet.fr/inp/courses/ENSE3A35EMIAAZ0/document/change_detection.pdf)

[image]

A slight change might get you the first and second changes easily: instead of working with the data, work with the difference of the data.  If I do that, then I get:

[image]

but I've had to add:

```
sigma <- 0.001
data_before_diff <- noiseless_data + rnorm(length(noiseless_data),0,sigma)
data <- diff(data_before_diff)
mu2diff <- 0.04
thresh <- 1
```

and then later:

```
 s[k] = (mu2diff - mu1)/sigma*(data[k] - (mu2diff + mu1)/2)
```

and

```
    tmp <- mu1
    mu1 <- mu2diff
    mu2diff <- tmp
```

To find the changes at the end of the signal, you'll probably need to change `mu2diff` to `-mu2diff` and check for that versus 0.

Note I've had to greatly reduce the noise variance and thus the threshold to get this to work.

---

**R Code Below**

```
# 30039
# CUSUM 

N <- 30

mu1 <- 0
mu2 <- 1
noiseless_data <- c(rep(mu1,N), seq(mu1,mu2,1/N), rep(mu2,N*4), seq(mu2,mu1,-1/N), rep(mu1,N))


sigma <- 0.1
data <- noiseless_data + rnorm(length(noiseless_data),0,sigma)

thresh <- 100

breaks <- rep(0,N)
num_breaks <- 0

s <- rep(0,length(data))
capS <- rep(0,length(data))
G <- rep(0,length(data))
for (k in 1:length(data))
{
  s[k] = (mu2 - mu1)/sigma*(data[k] - (mu2+mu1)/2)
  if (k==1)
  {
    capS[k] = s[k]
  }
  else
  {
    capS[k] = capS[k-1] + s[k]
  }

  G[k] <- max(0,capS[k] - min(capS[1:k]))

  if (abs(G[k]) > thresh)
  {
    #capS[k] <- 0
    num_breaks <- num_breaks + 1
    breaks[num_breaks] <- which.min(capS[1:k])
    tmp <- mu1
    mu1 <- mu2
    mu2 <- tmp
  }
}

first_break <- min(breaks[1:num_breaks])
last_break <- max(breaks[1:num_breaks])

plot(data,col="red", type="l")
lines(noiseless_data)
lines(c(first_break,first_break),c(0,1),col="blue", lwd=10)
lines(c(last_break,last_break),c(0,1),col="blue",lwd=10)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Actually, I want to detect the 4 points
1) point where it start rising 
2) point where it start stable
3) point where falling start
4) point where faling ends

Comment: @AadnanFarooqA Hence `to address the three zones: low level, changing level, and high level, you'll need to figure out the way to estimate the mean in the changing level` in my answer.

Comment: I am sorry i have deleted my comment

Comment: $c(rep(mu1,N), seq(mu1,mu2,1/N), rep(mu2,N*4), seq(mu2,mu1,-1/N), rep(mu1,N))$
'c' was not defined before so what is that?

Comment: @AadnanFarooqA In matlab that'd just be creation of a vector: `[mu1*ones(mu1,N), mu1:1/N:mu2, mu2*ones(1,4*N), mu2:-1/N:mu1, mu1*ones(1,N)];` (i.e. `c` is like `[]` in matlab).

Answer (score 0):

@Peter
I have trief to implement your code in MATLAB, but the output is not same as yours. Can you please suggest why is it so?
Second thing I want to know is why you used difference data?

```
data_before_diff <- noiseless_data + rnorm(length(noiseless_data),0,sigma)
data <- diff(data_before_diff)
```

[image]
    MATLAB CODE

```
N=30;

mu1=0;
mu2=1;
noiseless_data=[mu1*ones(mu1,N), mu1:1/N:mu2, mu2*ones(1,4*N), mu2:-1/N:mu1, mu1*ones(1,N)];

sigma=0.01;
data=noiseless_data+ rand(1,length(noiseless_data));

thresh=100;

breaks=zeros(1,N);

num_breaks=0;

s= zeros(1,length(data));

capS=zeros(1,length(data));

G=zeros(1,length(data));
for k =1:length(data)
    s(1,k) = (mu2 - mu1)/sigma*(data(1,k) - (mu2+mu1)/2);
    if (k==1)
      capS(1,k) = s(1,k);

    else

        capS(k) = capS(k-1) + s(k);

    end
    G(k) = max(0,capS(k) - min( capS(1:k)));

    if (abs(G(k)) > thresh)

%         capS(k)= 0
        num_breaks=num_breaks + 1;
        breaks(num_breaks) = find(min(capS(1:k)));
        tmp = mu1;
        mu1 = mu2;
        mu2 = tmp;
    end
end


first_break = min(breaks(1:num_breaks));
last_break = max(breaks(1:num_breaks));

plot(data,'r')
hold on
plot(noiseless_data)
line([first_break first_break],[0,1],'LineWidth',4,'Color','b')
line([last_break last_break],[0,1],'LineWidth',4,'Color','b')
hold off
```

Comment: I use "diff" data because that means what we are looking for are the edges in a signal that looks like  :          `________|   |________|   |__` rather than a linearly increasing change. The constant pieces become zero and the linearly changing pieces become non-zero sections.

Comment: @PeterK. How can i generate the noiseless data from the noise step data. As i have just noisy step data..

Comment: 2) When I random data then in some case i get the output as you showed. But when I fix the data than I cannot get the output. I have updated the code with your second suggestion