# Detecting special points in signal

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, signal-detection, detection

What tool/filter/mathematic operation would you use to detect the red points marked in this signal?

[image: signal]

As you can see there are several differentiated groups and I want to detect those moments in which changes occurs. I cannot use a fixed value for amplitude, because it might change.

I'm using MATLAB if someone wants to use some code for it.

Comment: Have a look at [this question and answers](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/30039/detect-to-rising-stable-and-falling-point-in-non-smooth-rectangular-wave/30046#30046) and see if that helps.

Comment: That would be what I want to do (more or less). The algorithm implementation doesn't work for me right now (some errors that I have to solve) but I'm trying to find some code to try it.